# using terraform to create aws NFS file share

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

any idea how i can use terraform to create nfs file share?

1. I need to create the s3 bucket

then

2. create nfs file share on existing storage gateway which I need to use the bucket name I created in step 1

any idea how to do in terraform?

Answer (score 0):

You will need 3 terraform resources :

1. [aws_s3_bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket)

> ```
> resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
>   bucket = "my-nfs-bucket"
>   acl    = "private"
>
>   tags = {
>     Author      = "me"
>     Environment =  "dev"
>   }
>
> }
> ```

2. [aws_storagegateway_gateway](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/storagegateway_gateway#s3-file-gateway)

> ```
> resource "aws_storagegateway_gateway" "my-storagegateway" {
>   gateway_ip_address = "1.2.3.4"
>   gateway_name       = "storage-gateway"
>   gateway_timezone   = "GMT"
>   gateway_type       = "FILE_S3"
> }
> ```

3. [aws_storagegateway_nfs_file_share](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/storagegateway_nfs_file_share)

> ```
>   resource "aws_storagegateway_nfs_file_share" "my_bucket" {
>       client_list  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
>       gateway_arn  = aws_storagegateway_gateway.my-storagegateway.arn
>       location_arn = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.arn
>       role_arn     = aws_iam_role.my-role.arn
>     }
> ```

You will also need in the ***role_arn*** key-value the ARN of the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that a file gateway assumes when it accesses the underlying storage.

- [aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role)
- [Managing your file gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/managing-gateway-file.html)

Comment: any idea how to enable bucket key for s3 bucket? I dont see that option in terraform

Comment: You mean for encryption ?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#enable-default-server-side-encryption

Comment: how to add prefix for the bucket?